# How to handle 1000 of records in phonegap application using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

In my application i need to retrieve 1000-10000 records from server using JSON and need to store it in sqlite DB for later use.

```
for (i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++)
    {
         //code to insert it into local DB
    }
```

I have used "for loop" for this process. I know this is not good when handling large data (1000 records). but i don't know alternate way to speed up / best way to handle this. If anybody know idea about this, please help me.

Thanks,

Comment: This is a little confusing. You've stated that you need to "retrieve" 1k+ records from a database but your code sample indicates that you're writing records instead. Which part of the problem exactly are you trying to solve for?

Comment: @Thomas Ingham The app is fetching from the server, then storing locally. The question is how to store large amounts of local data efficiently given that the JS runs on the main app thread, and will block while storing the records. Please correct me if I have mis-stated anything user985393.

Answer (score 1):

Since JavaScript is single threaded, here are the options that I see:

1. Write a phonegap plugin that will store the data using native code and thus can be run on a different thread.
2. Put your "code to insert in into local DB" block on a short interval using setInterval(). It will take your code alot longer to store the stuff but your UI will be more responsive.
3. Put up a "proccessing" dialog with a progress bar or a spinner while the records are being stored.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Using something like requestAnimationFrame would work well in this case since what you don't want to block is the UI and this should give you a simulated per-frame iteration. You would then measure your time to execute for inserts to chop off the process after ~50ms or so to keep things snappy. Great concept @Uncharted Space

Comment: @Thomas Ingham You are talking about the progress bar in option 3, right?

Comment: The entire thing could run against a yielded interval (..animationFrame) but yeah, specifically, the progress bar would want to happen using the best non-blocking timer possible. If he was using ext data store's (or knockout bindings) he wouldn't need to worry about the separate layer at all but that's out of scope with the question from the OP.